# Area of tree displayed by QTreeView not expands to its parent widget?

Tags: c++, qt, view, model, qtreeview

I use `QTreeView` and `QStandardItemModel` to  display its contents (read from xml file) in a `tree view`. The file parser works just OK, but when I use the view to display the data, the `sizePolicy` just doesn't work.
Why? How to make the area of tree expand?
(It shows like below, which tree view doesn't expand?)

picture of the display of the tree:
[image]

code (edited to add "layout" part, but not work, either.):

```
...
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel();
preOrder(doc.firstChild(), model);
view = new QTreeView(pageDetails);
view->setModel(model);

model->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList(""));

QHBoxLayout* lay=new QHBoxLayout(pageDetails);
lay->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
lay->addWidget(view);
view->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
pageDetails->setLayout(lay);

view->show();
```

Comment: Did you add your `QTreeView` to parent widget's layout?

Comment: @user2155932 How to add it?

Comment: Look [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html)

Comment: You should also call `QWidget::setLayout` on your parent widget with your created layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem solved now:
[image]

But still don't know how to remove the header...
**The problem is caused by Qt Designer.** I use it to add the parent widget ui, but set it a horizonal layout in the designer(somewhat difficult to find).
I just don't know why the code above just doesn't work in this case.

PS:
If I left the code commented:

```
//QHBoxLayout* lay=new QHBoxLayout(pageDetails);
//lay->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
//lay->addWidget(view);
//view->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
//pageDetails->setLayout(lay);
```

It appears:
[image]

PS2:
remove header successfully!:
comment `model->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList(""));`
add `view->header()->setVisible(false);`

Comment: view->setHeaderHidden(false)